# SAS EG is unable to connect to SAS APP Sever context also unable to validate sas Logical workspace server and sas grid server in management console

Tags: sas, lsf

SAS Environment details  sas 9.4_M3
2 metadata server 19 grid nodes 1 grid master 2 web servers
issue in grid:
sas eg is unable to connect to sasAPP/ sasAPPgrid  server context. error message "Unable to establish connection with SAS APP.
also when tried to validate servers in SMC below server failed
SASApp Logical grid Server and SASApp Logical Workspace Server
Below were the error in Object spawner Logs.

> 2017-11-03T15:28:06,157 ERROR [00532573] :saspmgr0 -
>   2017-11-03T15:28:06,000 (gridrun.c:1047) - processStartJob: Error
>   starting job, status=0x81ffe803 2017-11-03T15:28:06,157 ERROR
>   [00532573] :saspmgr0 -  PROVIDER(Platform): Bad host name, host group
>   name or cluster name 2017-11-03T15:28:06,157 ERROR [00532573]
>   :saspmgr0 -  Grid job failed to run. 2017-11-03T15:28:06,157 ERROR
>   [00532556] :f401099 - Grid job failed to run. 2017-11-03T15:28:06,157
>   ERROR [00532556] :f401099 - The launch of server SASApp - Workspace
>   Server for user f401099 failed. 2017-11-03T15:28:06,158 ERROR
>   [00532556] :f401099 - The specified uuid
>   9762CD6B-30D8-7341-9821-5D7A337756D2 did not match any process managed
>   by this spawner. 2017-11-03T15:28:06,158 INFO  [00532556] :saspmgr0 -
>   Client connection 4112 for user f401099 closed.

I also see error in connect spawner Logs.
issue though resolved after restarting LSF however i want to understand the root cause since this issue occurred thrice in 7 days.

Comment: Since you mention things like LSF scheduler and grid servers, I'm assuming this is an enterprise environment. This is therefore typically a question for the SAS support. That's what they're for and that's why your company pays the big bucks.

Comment: yes it is and i have opened a ticket with sas support already however still did not get any reply from them

Comment: That is unfortunately typical. Right when their SLA period will be about to expire they'll respond to your ticket asking you for "more logs" :)

Comment: i have provided logs to them already twice and also all the details regarding issue however still they don't know the root cause they suggested after restarting lsf issue should be resolved which is true but i wanted to understand why is this happening since it happened thrice in last 7 days and every time restarting lsf is not something i want to do.